# Does convergence in distribution of components imply convergence for the random vector too?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued random variables such that along each component $j:1 \leq j \leq d,$ we have $\{(X_n)_j\} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}U[0,1]$, where $U[0,1]$ denotes the uniform random variable on $[0,1].$ Can we say that $\{X_n\} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}U[0,1]^d$ ?

Does the converse hold true ? i.e, if $\{X_n\} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}U[0,1]^d$ then does $\{(X_n)_j\} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}U[0,1]$ hold true ?

Answer (score 5):

The first assertion is wrong. For the simplest case, take $d = 2$, and  $X_n \equiv (X, X)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, where $X \sim U[0, 1]$. It can be easily seen that the support of $X_n$ is $\{(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]: x = y\}$, which has Lebesgue measure $0$. Thus $X_n$ cannot converge weakly to a $U([0, 1] \times [0, 1])$ random vector, whose support is the unit square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$, which has Lebesgue measure $1$.

The converse assertion is correct, by the continuous mapping theorem.

---

More details on disproving the first statement:
If $X_n \Rightarrow U$, where $U \sim U([0, 1] \times [0, 1])$. Then for $S = \{(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]: x = y\} $, we have $$P[X_n \in S] \to P[U \in S],\tag{1}$$ since $P[U \in \partial S] = 0$.

However, $P[X_n \in S] = P[X = X] = 1$, while $P[U \in S] = \int_S 1 dxdy = 0$. Hence $(1)$ fails to hold, a contradiction.